# Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: command-line, odbc, cmd, osql

I am trying to connect to list the servers on my network using `osql.exe -L`. Instead of a list of servers, however, I get the following error:

`[ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

I'm not sure what's causing this problem - any pointers leading in the right direction will be helpful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The DSN is case sensitive, make sure your putting in the right name.  It should match whatever you have in your odbc.ini file (unix) or in the "ODBC Data Source Administrator" (windows).